# Laravel created event returning the wrong record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-events

I'm currently using Laravel observers to implement events in my project, however, I ran into some problem where the created event returns a wrong record, for example, I create a record called Like that has post_id set to 2 and user_id set to 1, so the laravel created event should return this record right? except it returns a record where post_id is set to 0 and user_id set to 1.
my LikeObserver class:

```
class LikeObserver
{
/**
 * Handle the like "created" event.
 *
 * @param  \App\Like  $like
 * @return void
 */
public function created(Like $like)
{
    dd($like);
    $postId = $like->post_id;
    Post::find($postId)->increment('likes_count');
}
}
```

as you can see whenever i dump the newly created record it returns this:
[image: what laravel returns]

my LikeController class:

```
class LikeController extends Controller
{
public function insert(Request $request)
{
    if(Like::where('user_id','1')->find($request->post_id))
    {
        return;
    }
    $like = Like::create(['post_id'=>$request->post_id,'user_id' => '1']);
}

public function remove(Request $request)
{
    Like::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->findOrFail($request->post_id)->delete();
}
}
```

I pass post_id set to 2, however, Laravel returns the newly created record with post_id set to 0.

Comment: what's the result of `dd($request->post_id)` in insert function?

Comment: @am05mhz it dumps the correct post_id which is 2

Comment: i see nothing wrong then, except maybe a typo somewhere

Comment: @am05mhz me neither its really hard to know if its a problem on laravel's end.. i tried googling around but didn't find a similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so apparently the fix was to use the creating event instead of the created event... this does return the correct record

```
public  static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function ($like){
     //returns the correct record.
     dd($like);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class LikeController extends Controller
{
    public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $like = Like::firstOrCreate([
            'user_id' => '1',
            'post_id' => $request->post_id,
        ]);

        if(! $like->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public function remove(Request $request)
    {
        Like::where([
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'post_id' => $request->post_id,
        ])->first()->delete();
    }
}
```